# why are plugin connected signal not working after saving?

Tags: plugins, godot, gdscript

I've created a plugin and it works fine when I open the project but as soon as I press ctrl + s to save the scene for the first time since opening, the buttons on the plugin (`Close_btn` in this case) stop working

```
tool
extends EditorPlugin

var Key_Btn=null;
var UI=load("res://addons/Plugin_Name/UI.tscn").instance();

func show_UI():
    get_editor_interface().add_child(UI)

func close_UI():
    if(get_editor_interface().has_node(UI.name)):
        get_editor_interface().remove_child(UI);


func _enter_tree():
    
    Key_Btn=Button.new();
    Key_Btn.text=" Key ";
    Key_Btn.flat=true;
    add_control_to_container(CONTAINER_CANVAS_EDITOR_MENU,Key_Btn)
    Key_Btn.connect("pressed",self,"show_UI")
    

func _exit_tree():
    close_UI();
    remove_control_from_container(CONTAINER_CANVAS_EDITOR_MENU,Key_Btn)
```

This is what the plugin button looks like:
[image]

The UI that pops up when you press the button:
[image]

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. I did modify the UI as I describe below. However, with your code, at no point the UI or the button to open it stopped working.

This is what I tried (closing and opening the project between tests):

- Saving, then opening the UI. Then closing the UI and opening it again.
- Opening the UI, then closing it, then saving, then opening it again.
- Opening the UI, saving with the UI open, closing it, then opening it again.

I tested on Godot 3.3, 3.4,, 3.4.3 and 3.5 beta 1.

---

Since you have a `Button` called Transparent Background. I had it set to Full Rect, and set the alpha of its `self_modulate` to make it transparent. Consequently it won't let me interact with anything in the editor…

To be able to close the UI, I had to add a script to Control Main that looks like this:

```
tool
extends Control

func close():
    if is_inside_tree():
        get_parent().remove_child(self)
```

*Don't forget to make a tool script.*

And I connected the press signal from the Transparent Background and Close_btn to the `close` method I added.

*An alternative would have been to emit a signal from the `UI` and on the `EditorPlugin` have it connected to `close_UI`… I didn't do that because I didn't want to change your code. And since it all worked with that code, I can say that issue for you is not that code.*

---

Also be aware that you load an instance the `UI` scene on the initialization of your `EditorPlugin`. In consequence…

Some modifications to that scene won't be reflected on the `EditorPlugin` until you disable and enable it again, or load the project again.

And I say "some modifications", because you will see reflected the modifications to the resources it had when loaded. For example, I can modify the script I attached, or re-import texture, and so on. *However, if I replace the resource with a new one, I will see the old resource on the already loaded `UI`.*

With that in mind, I tried modifying the script I attached to introduce an error and saved… And the UI still appears. Except, since the script I attached was not working, I could not close the `UI`, so I had to close Godot altogether.

In fact, the only way I have been able to make the button stop working after saving was by introducing an error in the `EditorPlugin` code and saving. I can only assume this is what happened to you.